# Git tagging: checkout tag, make changes, push to new tag

Tags: git

I have been reading all morning trying to figure out how tagging works in git and I'm confused, hoping someone can clarify for me. I forked a public codebase, would like to checkout the v3.0.7 tag, modify/add files, commit them, and create a new tag v3.0.7.1. This is as far as I'm getting before I'm totally lost.

```
git clone https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo.git
git checkout tags/v3.0.7 -b v3.0.7.1
# make changes
git commit -m 'made some changes for 3.0.7.1'
# Do something here that I don't understand... maybe something like:
# git checkout master; git merge v3.0.7.1
# now I'm extra lost. 
# push to tag 3.0.7.1 somehow
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I read through that page but I still don't understand what branch to push the tags to or how to push any of it to a remote repository

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating a local branch with the same name that your tag will get. Normally, it would be something like:

```
git checkout -b v3.0.7.x 3.0.7 # create local v3.0.7.x branch from v3.0.7
# do changes
git add .
git commit -m "Changes for v3.0.7.1"
git tag v3.0.7.1
```

That should be it

Comment: that makes sense, but what do I do about pushing to the remote branch at that point? i.e. which branch do I push to? a new remote branch called v3.0.7.x ?

Comment: tags are not related to branches, they can be pushed to git event when the branch is deleted